# Urllib2 throwing error of <class 'urllib2.URLError'>

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I cannot seem to see why this is not working.

```
import urllib2
import sys

try:
    def script_create():
        urllib2.urlopen("http://"+sys.argv[1]+":"+sys.argv[2]+"/?search=%00{.+"+save+".}")
except Exception as e:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print(e)
```

by executing this script like:

```
python myfile.py 192.168.1.2 4444
```

it gives:

```
<class 'urllib2.URLError'>
```

Thanks.

Can someone help out please?

Thanks

Comment: What's the value of `save`? Also, you appear to be defining your function in a `try` block, but you never call it.

Comment: If, instead of a try/except, you simple allow the Exception to crash your script, you might be able to get more information from the traceback about what went wrong.

Comment: save is just a string @perfect5th

Comment: See my previous comment about raising the Exception. Would be useful to see the full traceback.

Comment: this may be more informative: `print(e.__dict__)`